# How to run debug app version on a 'debug' Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-realtime-database

in the Google I/O 2016 sessions the big improvements towards full integration of Firebase has been shown. In my apps, I'm trying to migrate to the new solution(s) but have several questions. One of them is the following:

In my Firebase apps, I used a parameter to define the Firebase database as follows (gradle):

gradle.properties file:

```
FIREBASE_REF_REL="https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/"
FIREBASE_REF_DEB="https://xxxxxxx-dev.firebaseio.com/"
```

build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'FIREBASE_ROOT_URL', FIREBASE_REF_DEB
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'FIREBASE_ROOT_URL', FIREBASE_REF_REL
        }
        return true
    }
```

This allowed me to run my debug apps against a debug Firebase environment which helped me to test changes in the datamodel and security rules without affecting the production environment.

In the new Firebase solution this does not seem possible anymore because of the generated `google-services.json` file which contains the Firebase reference (as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered).

When trying to reference my debug database I get the following type of errors:

```
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid URL (https://xxxxxxx-dev.firebaseio.com/) passed to getReference().  URL was expected to match configured Database URL: https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com
```

My question: what is the correct way/best practice to run an app against a test Firebase database in the new situation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am not sure that it is the best practice.

You can use different `google-services.json` files.
I am investiganting about the current plugin (`com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`) if it supports build types.
The previous one (`com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.X`) supported flavors but not types.

In any case you should be able to use somenthing like this:

```
app/src/release/google-services.json
app/google-services.json
```

In this case the plugin looks in the locations and stops when it finds a `google-services.json` file.

In this way you should be able to use different firebase apps for debug and release.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I ended up using a structure like this:    `project\app\src\debug\google-services.json
project\app\src\release\google-services.json`    Debug builds now work on a dedicated Firebase database (with the debug SHA1) while release version of the app work on a production Firebase database.

Comment: @Peter if this solved your issue, as you said, please mark it as correct. Just adding this link so it helps others like me --> [Organizing your Firebase-enabled Android app builds](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html).

Comment: Here is another good blogpost: https://medium.com/@Miqubel/multiple-build-types-in-firebase-on-android-6f6715f6dd83#.da7qmrzbx

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for various google-services.json files as the answer above specifies. Instead in Firebase you create a project. Each project can have multiple apps (even across different platforms).

In my case for instance I have two build types (debug and release) and two productFlavors resulting in 4 apps with different package names:

- fullDebug: com.company.myapp.debug
- fullRelease: com.company.myapp
- demoDebug: com.company.myapp.demo.debug
- demoRelease: com.company.myapp.demo

One google-services.json file covers all of these variants and should just be put into the app module of your Android Studio project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I'm trying to achieve is running the debug version of my app on a 'debug' Firebase database (which is a different from the 'release' database). I don't see how I can achieve this with a single google-services.json file. The solution provided by @Gabriele Mariotti seems the best fit at this moment.

Comment: you can achieve this because you can specify a different clientinfo in that json that uses a different package name to point to other "project" so you can have your debug build be something like debug.com.your.package and point it to a different place

Comment: I don't see how creating a different app on firebase will create a debug database.

Comment: Some parts of Firebase (auth, database, storage and hosting) are common for all project's apps. Your solution will not create debug database.