# How can I separate testing and production data in my Firebase Database?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each Firebase project includes only one JSON tree for data. Best practices dictate that tests should be run on a separate database from production data. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Some things I considered:

- Using multiple sub-trees within the same project for testing and production - This seems messy and the testing and production data are hardly separated.
- Setting up multiple Firebase projects for testing and production - This seems like the best answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360919/how-to-run-debug-app-version-on-a-debug-firebase-database) related to Android. But I'm not sure how to set up multiple `GoogleService-Info.plist` files in Xcode and switch between them based on my app's Configuration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create multiple Firebase projects. Each project has its own plist file.

`FIRApp` has a custom configuration option. Download the plist for your testing/debug project, rename it and load like below.

```
#if DEBUG
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-dev" ofType:@"plist"];
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
#else
    [FIRApp configure];
#endif
```

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0)

Comment: Almost a year later I want to confirm that for every new project now using Firebase, I create two separate Firebase projects: One for testing/dev, and one for production.

Comment: Also it's recommended in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#managing_project_aliases

Comment: In addition to doing this, I would also create a separate project in FireBase so that the data isn't shared.

Comment: @pejalo if you put this as an answer here I'll upvote it. I think since making two separate firebase projects is a good answer to the question you asked (though the one above isn't wrong) it should be posted and made more obvious. After reading this, I'll be creating two separate projects myself

Comment: @KyleSomers I edited this answer to explicitly state what I thought was already implied

Comment: @pejalo is this to be written in the build phases, or in the the app delegate?

Comment: @AakashDave In the app delegate

Comment: @pejalo thanks mate. After that I am stuck here with pods. Can you give a hand? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102884/pods-not-used-in-any-concrete-target