# How to work on Firebase project without impacting users?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to be able to work on my app without impacting my current users. However, I still want to work with the current data structure and files in storage. I want to test posting data and querying data without users seeing these actions. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Currently I thought about just making another project in Firebase. I can export the JSON for the database, but I won't be able to access the files in storage? I don't see a way to export all of the files in storage so I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

**Update**

Not sure if I should delete this question at it appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021100/how-can-i-separate-testing-and-production-data-in-my-firebase-database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strongly advised to have different projects for different environments (dev, test, stage, prod, etc). You should not be testing in production.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

If you're using iOS you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021100/how-can-i-separate-testing-and-production-data-in-my-firebase-database), [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/cohenadair/3a2aff5084603bfa65824f09cf74206e), or 
[this blog post](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application) you can do this rather easily by manually configuring your GoogleService-Info.plist like this:

```
// Configure with manual options.
let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:27992087142:ios:2a4732a34787067a", gcmSenderID: "27992087142")
secondaryOptions.bundleID = "com.google.firebase.devrel.FiroptionConfiguration"
secondaryOptions.apiKey = "AIzaSyBicqfAZPvMgC7NZkjayUEsrepxuXzZDsk"
secondaryOptions.clientID = "27992087142-ola6qe637ulk8780vl8mo5vogegkm23n.apps.googleusercontent.com"
secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "myproject.appspot.com"
```

You can incorporate this into your AppDelegate like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if !isDebug {
        print("setting config for release")
        let releaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:27992087142:ios:2a4732a34787067a", gcmSenderID: "27992087142")
        releaseOptions.bundleID = "com.myProject"
        releaseOptions.apiKey = "AIzaSyBicqfAZPvMgC7NZkjayUEsrepxuXzZDsk"
        releaseOptions.clientID = "27992087142-ola6qe637ulk8780vl8mo5vogegkm23n.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        releaseOptions.databaseURL = "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
        releaseOptions.storageBucket = "myproject.appspot.com"
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: releaseOptions)
    }
    else {
        print("setting config for debug")
        let debugOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "DebugID", gcmSenderID: "DebugSender")
        debugOptions.bundleID = "com.myProjectDebug"
        debugOptions.apiKey = "Debug API key"
        debugOptions.clientID = "Debug Client ID
        debugOptions.databaseURL = "https://myprojectDebug.firebaseio.com"
        debugOptions.storageBucket = "myprojectDebug.appspot.com"
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: debugOptions)
    }
    return true
}
```

Then all you need to do if flip the value of `isDebug` to determine which version of the app is loaded. Using this method also allows for analytics to work on both versions of the app. For production code just remove `isDebug` and the else case.